# How to use pg-dump for heroku

Tags: django, heroku, upload, pg-dump

I'm trying to upload a database to my heroku app, I'm using

```
$ PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

But, to do it, I have to replace localhost with my heroku app host. How do I know what my host is?

Sorry for asking such a simple question, but I'm starting with heroku and there're still a lot I have to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have postgresql installed and running